# vim-test :TestSuite return message Not a test file

Tags: neovim, microsoft-windows, filetype-javascript, unit-testing, plugin-vim-test

It's a really simple setup. I'm actually following along with the modern vim book. (I've been using vim emulation on IDEs for years and want to fully dive in).

Anyway, my project structure is:

- jasmine-test

  - lib/

    - homophoner.js
  - node_modules/
  - spec/

    - Support/
    - jasmine.json
    - homophonerSpec.js
  - .gitignore
  - package.json

Opening the homophonerSpec.js file and running the :TestSuite command outputs the message "Not a test file" (I have tried running nvim and vim from Windows Terminal)

Note:
I only have jasmine installed locally in the package.json file.

```
{
  "name": "test-jasmine",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jasmine"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "jasmine": "^2.8.0",
    "lodash-node": "^3.10.2"
  }
}
```

I've tried going through the README, but I cannot find anything that I'm supposed to do. I must be missing a dependency.

I've tried in both vim and nvim wth the same result.

This is the plugin that I am using to try to run the tests https://github.com/vim-test/vim-test

And here's the [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/vim-test/vim-test/issues/570).

Comment: Are you running `vim` from the top directory? As in, `cd jasmint-test`, then `vim spec/homophonerSpec.js`? I can see how it would need to be in the top-level directory to properly detect which testing framework is in use...

Comment: Yes, my steps have been:
1. cd jasmine-test
2. vim
3. (In Vim) e: spec/homophonerSpec.js

My working directory should be jasmine_test.

Comment: Not sure if it's important but I installed the plugin using minpac (instead of vim-plug per the readme).  And I'm running vim/nvim via a window's terminal window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found the issue and a workaround.  The issue is on Windows the path separator is `\` and not `/` as is written in the code.

There is also a Windows in jasmine.vim when using the jasmine executable from within `node_modules` also related to path separators.

I will raise a PR to the vim-test github repo to resolve this, but here is a workaround for windows:

```
let g:test#javascript#jasmine#file_pattern = '\v^spec[\\/].*spec\.(js|jsx|coffee)$'
let test#javascript#jasmine#executable = 'npx jasmine'
```